# Matplotlib Annotate using values from DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to annotate a chart to include the plotted values of the x-axis as well as additional information from the DataFrame.  I am able to annotate the values from the x-axis but not sure how I can add additional information from the data frame. In my example below I am annotating the x-axis which are the values from the **Completion** column but also want to add the **Completed** and **Participants** values from the DataFrame.

For example the **Running** **Completion** is 20% but I want my annotation to show the **Completed** and **Participants** values in the format - 20% (2/10). Below is sample code that can reproduce my scenario as well as current and desired results.  Any help is appreciated.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

mydict = {
    'Event': ['Running', 'Swimming', 'Biking', 'Hiking'],
    'Completed': [2, 4, 3, 7],
    'Participants': [10, 20, 35, 10]}

df = pd.DataFrame(mydict).set_index('Event')
df = df.assign(Completion=(df.Completed/df.Participants) * 100)
print(df)

plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 3))
ax = sns.barplot(x=df.Completion, y=df.index, color="cyan", orient='h')

for i in ax.patches:
    ax.text(i.get_width() + .4,
            i.get_y() + .67,
            str(round((i.get_width()), 2)) + '%', fontsize=10)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

**DataFrame:**

```
          Completed  Participants  Completion
Event                                        
Running           2            10   20.000000
Swimming          4            20   20.000000
Biking            3            35    8.571429
Hiking            7            10   70.000000
```

**Current Output:**

[image]

**Desired Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the columns `Completed` and `Participants` as well when you annotate:

```
for (c,p), i in zip(df[["Completed","Participants"]].values, ax.patches):
    ax.text(i.get_width() + .4,
            i.get_y() + .67,
            str(round((i.get_width()), 2)) + '%' + f" ({c}/{p})", fontsize=10)
```

Comment: This is awesome. That accomplishes what I was looking for. Thanks for the help!